# is this unbind bug still exist in jQuery

Tags: jquery, unbind

today i try to make a code with jQuery bind/unbind event but, it always goes wrong if i use unbind, then i search to the net about unbinding an event, is this bug http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/1043  still exist in jQuery???(assume in last version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's closed as "WONTFIX" so that means it still exists, and will continue to exist.  There is a workaround in the bug report though:

> This can be worked around by using removeAttr() instead

However that bug is about unbinding events that weren't bound with jQuery - you say you're using `bind()` so I'm not sure that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To help with your problem, some source code would be needed.

To answer your question about the bug, it has been marked as "**wontfix**", which should be quite self-explanatory. A workaround is provided in the comments for the bug, though.